# How to set up a Mapping while indexing data through bulk API in Elasticsearch-PHP?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/blog/analyzing-network-packets-with-wireshark-elasticsearch-and-kibana), and I need to do it in PHP, so I have to use Elasticsearch-php. In this particular step, I am trying to set up a mapping for elasticsearch and also bulk index data from a `.json` file. So I looked into examples [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_index_management_operations.html) and [here][3], and following is my code.

The problem is taht it gives me

```
Elasticsearch PHP client created successfully!

Fatal error: Uncaught Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [dynamic]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [dynamic]"},"status":400} in /var/www/html/Tests/Test/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:610 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/Tests/Test/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php(273): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->process4xxError(Array, Array, Array) #1 /var/www/html/Tests/Test/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php(25): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}(Array) #2 /var/www/html/Tests/Test/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Future/CompletedFutureValue.php(55): React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL) #3 /var/www/html/Tests/Test/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/ in /var/www/html/Tests/Test/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php on line 610
```

and when I comment out the line `"dynamic" => "false"`, I get

```
Elasticsearch PHP client created successfully!

Fatal error: Uncaught Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected a simple value for field [properties] but found [START_OBJECT]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected a simple value for field [properties] but found [START_OBJECT]"},"status":400} in /var/www/html/Tests/Test/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:610 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/Tests/Test/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php(273): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->process4xxError(Array, Array, Array) #1 /var/www/html/Tests/Test/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php(25): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}(Array) #2 /var/www/html/Tests/Test/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Future/CompletedFutureValue.php(55): React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then(O in /var/www/html/Tests/Test/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php on line 610
```

What am I missing? How should I fix this?

```
<?php 


require_once("vendor/autoload.php");
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

$esClient = ClientBuilder::create()->build();

echo "Elasticsearch PHP client created successfully!<br>";//check

$indexParams = array();
$indexParams['index'] = "test_packets_index";
$indexParams['type'] = "testPacketsType";

$indexParams['body'] = [
    'mappings' => [
        "testPacketsType" => [

            //"dynamic" => "false",
            "properties" => [



                "timestamp" => [
                    "type" => "date"
                ],



                "layers" => [
                    "properties" => [
                        "ip" => [
                            "properties" => [
                                "ip_ip_src" => [
                                    "type" => "ip"
                                ],
                                "ip_ip_dst" => [
                                    "type" => "ip"
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]



            ]
        ]
    ]
];






$jsonFileHandle = fopen("packets.json", "r");
if ($jsonFileHandle) {
    while (  ($line = fgets($jsonFileHandle))  !==  FALSE  ) {

        if ( !($line == "") ) {
            $indexParams['body'][] = json_decode($line, true);
        }

    }
}
fclose($jsonFileHandle);
#print_r($indexParams['body']);//check



$indexingResponse = $esClient->bulk($indexParams);
echo "Result: "; print_r($indexingResponse); echo "<br>";//check


?>
```

[3]: https : //www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_indexing_documents.html

Comment: `"false" != false`. First is `string`, second is `bool`.

Comment: @bato3 I don't recognize where I have compared a "false" with a false. Can you elaborate a bit?